# tableadapter VB.net 2008 - retrieve identity

Tags: vb.net, identity, tableadapter

I am inserting a record to a MSSQL table using a tableadapter using something like:
Dim da_mytable As New t_mytableTableAdapter
da_mytable.Insert(xxxx,xxxx,xxxx)

The SQL table has an identity field which is also the PK for the table.

The insert works fine, but my question is how to return the ID that was used on the insert.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution described here.

http://blogs.msdn.com/smartclientdata/archive/2005/10/31/ReturnIdentityValueQuery.aspx